# React/pdf magen en los View

Tags: reactjs, frontend

estuve realizando un reporte en pdf con react/pdf, pero el problema es que necesito crear un View general y dentro de el mas view para poder simular tablas, todo esto se recorre en un ciclo pero el problema es que cuando pasa a la página siguiente nunca se respeta el margen de abajo y los elementos pasan por encima hasta finalmente llegar a la otra página.